# Ubuntu 20.04 remote assistance from Windows

Tags: remote, remote-access, remote-assistance

Does anyone know a software I can install in both Ubuntu and Windows to remote assist users on Linux by screen sharing?

The IT assistance team uses Windows, the user needing assistance uses Ubuntu 20.04.

On Windows I'd like to open `cmd`, connect via `ssh` to the client, and run the share screen software on the target client. I tried Remmina but it doesn't work on Windows. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

TeamViewer works on Windows and Linux. The software doesn't need any further configuration on the client side.
Anydesk may be another alternative to TeamViewer.

The Linux client could install a RDP server like xrdp as well, but this needs more work plus may the client change his router configuration in case the computer to be accessed it sitting behind a router.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply, the problem with team viewer is that the connections goes through their server so it’s not security compliance. I need something totally local.

Comment: That's correct. As said, working with an RDP Server on the Ubuntu side will work, too. Every Windows installation has a RDP client, too. However, as installing an RDP server on the Ubuntu side plus possibly configuring the firewall of a router the Ubuntu computer is sitting behind is not easy and prone to errors. Plus opening ports on a router adds new potential security issues.

Comment: Thanks again, but i don’t need to rdp the client, i need the user to share their screen.